# warp-rnnt install Error (Exception: CPU version is not implemented)

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, voice-recognition, warp

[image]

I try to install **warp-rnnt** using pip
there was an error

**Exception : CPU version is not implemented**

here is an **error message** below

```py
(base) C:\Users\user>pip install warp_rnnt
Collecting warp_rnnt
  Using cached warp_rnnt-0.7.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ftzpujnm\warp-rnnt_26fb0d2ac033439f8b87b32ca75b270c\setup.py", line 22, in <module>
          raise Exception("CPU version is not implemented")
      Exception: CPU version is not implemented
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

and my computer setting is

```py
OS : window 10
GPU : RTX 3070 Ti
cuda : 11.1
cudnn : 8.1.1
tensorflow : 2.4.0
tensorflow-gpu : 2.4.0
python : 3.7
```

I want install `warp-rnnt`
What is wrong with my computer??

I try to found "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ftzpujnm\warp-rnnt_26fb0d2ac033439f8b87b32ca75b270c\setup.py" file
but there is no directory

and I already setting cuda, cudnn "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE"